# Cocoa App: How distribute beta versions?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, testing, distribution, beta

Until today I've developed and tested by myself all the versions of my app!
I would like to begin to release some versions for beta tester, to have a better product to release! But I really don't know how do that!

I had thought to upload the beta version on my website in a password protected folder and sent to my testers a notification (by e-mail) about the availability of a new beta version.

Or to upload the beta version on a restricted area of my website and mail to my tester a dynamic link (with an expiration time) to the new available beta.

These are some good way or I can do that better?

Thanks in advance for your replies!

---

**EDIT**

I already have some beta tester, I'm not searching for new one! I'm asking only for a suggestion on how send my beta version to my tester!

---

**EDIT 2**

The app I want to send to my testers is a MAC OS X application, not an iPhone OS app!
Otherwise, I would like to distribute the app (only to my beta testers) in a secure way ... so I can't use software updates frameworks as Sparkle!

Comment: “Otherwise, I would like to distribute the app (only to my beta testers) in a secure way ... so I can't use software updates frameworks as Sparkle!” Non-sequitur. There's no reason why you can't use Sparkle in a beta app. As neoneye suggests in the current version of his answer, have a different appcast for betas. We do this in Adium and it works well.

Comment: Yes, you are right! But if I use an appcast to distribute my beta versions, it's easy for everyone to download the beta from my website! I don't want that a beta version appears on internet before to release the master version, because my app is not completely free! I hope you get the idea of what I mean!

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

Then have 2 appcasts. One for the regular users. Another one for the testers.

SECOND REPLY:

Ok, so you already have testers and it's a cocoa program. Then you can use [Sparkle](http://sparkle.andymatuschak.org/) to distribute updates of your app.

FIRST REPLY:

Send out a press release via [prmac](http://prmac.com/). Requesting beta testers, free licenses to anyone that  contributes. This will give you some PR as well (which is difficult to get).

Or ask on #macdev or #macsb on the freenode IRC server. However people may easily get offended if you mention its a product and its not free. I have tried seeking testers this way for my own program but it was a total failure. However even though you choose your words wisely, you may only get a few people to take a peek at your product that way.

Or just ask this question on the [macsb](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/macsb/) mailing list.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I already have found some beta tester ... but I don't know what is the best way to send them the beta version!

Comment: Thanks again! I already use Sparkle to release my update to my customers! But now I'm asking for a suggestion on how send only to my beta testers a beta version of my app ... and I would like to use a secure way! Sparkle isn't a good solution in this case!

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending it to other developers (who have their own device deployment identifier) then you can send them the binary, and they'll be able to install it onto their own iPhones. However, if you want to send it to end users who have iPhones then you'll have to get their device ID and register it as a device on your account, and then provide a per-binary signed for each one of their devices.

They'll then be able to take the app, put it in iTunes, and then it will be sync'd across to their iPhone.

Comment: This is exactly how we handle beta testing.  Works really well.  Simple drag-and-drop of the binary on the iTunes window and the app is there for the user to test.

Comment: Of course, that only applies to the iPhone, which doesn't help with a Cocoa app. Your answer only helps this questioner if he meant to say Cocoa Touch.

Comment: Thanks! But my app isn't an iPhone app! It's a mac OS X application!

Comment: OK, if it's not an iPhone app, what's the problem? Give them a DMG from your website, if necessary, behind a password-protected login (which you give them). If you're worried about piracy or them passing it on, have some code which checks for some particular hardware (like ethernet address) or put in a giant nag screen which says 'licensed to ...' which is compiled into the app. I'm not really sure what kind of difficulty you're running into with making it available for download; perhaps you could update the question appropriately?